# Laravel 5 Eloquent Relations

Tags: laravel, relationship, belongs-to

I have a prolem here with 2-level far relations between models. It's classic eCommerce website with expected structure where you have a product table, galleries and images. Product and Image has gallery_id so every gallery has potencialy many Images. This is my solution which doesn't work. Returns "Trying to get property 'images' of non-object".

VIEW Product.blade.php

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($product->gallery->images as $image)
        <li><img src="{{ asset($image->path) }}" alt="" data-image="{{ asset($image->path) }}"></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

MODEL Product.php

```
public function gallery()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Gallery');
}
```

MODEL Gallery.php

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
}
```

Why I can't access images from product view by $product->gallery->images?

Comment: shouldn't you check that `$product->gallery` exists before apptempting to loop through the images?

Comment: $product->gallery returns null, that means...? :)

Comment: It means the product does not have a gallery relation

Comment: Yeah, understand... but don't know why, that relation exists in database. Do I have to register created models after its made by artisan?

Comment: What is the column name in your products table for the gallery id?

Comment: 'gallery_id', the same column name has Images table

Comment: OK, it's solved. The problem was in database structure. So my original solution works. Sorry and thanks a lot for your time Don and Ross.